# Why are these Grease Pencil objects moving together when I animate them?

Tags: objects, grease-pencil

[image]

Using Blender 2.83, either in the 2D or in the general layout, how can I select individual objects having different layers and different materials? I want to animate objects individually.

I am a newbie to blender and new to animation.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that both of your objects are one single *Grease Pencil* object. If you look in the *Outliner* in your video (to the right), you will see that you have something highlighted in the list called **Stroke**. And both of these objects are part of it. Hence, why you can't move them independent of one another. If you want independent objects in 2D, you need to create a unique grease pencil object for each of them. This can be done in Object Mode, from the *Add* menu (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd>).